# Row issue with Ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to manipulate the style of a data-table being used with ag-grid plugin. The background colour of each row seems to cut off before the end of the table when it's inside of a CSS overflow parent. What can I do to avoid that cut off so that everything is in colour?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a plunker or similar that can be looked at?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by
using `overflow: auto` on `ag-body-viewport` class and remove `width: 100%` on the `.ag-body-container{}` class, in case you have that.